# Input a folder in my build

Tags: xml, xslt, ant

I would to know how to make my folder contening xml files an input for my build.xml (i use ant)

In fact, I have to convert many .xml files, of course they have the same informations and nodes in.

So right now, in my build.xml I use this types of lines :

```
<xslt style="./rules.xsl" in="./1.xml" out="1.txt" />
<xslt style="./rules.xsl" in="./2.xml" out="2.txt" />
<xslt style="./rules.xsl" in="./3.xml" out="3.txt" />
```

But today I have to do it with many many files, how can I "select" a folder contening my xml ?

Thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 0):

just use the basedir attributes of the xslt task and leave blanks the in and out

```
<xslt style="rules.xsl" basedir="."  destdir='.' includes='*.xml' extension='.txt'/>
```

for more information you can refer to the ant's [XSLT task documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html)

Comment: so i just have to place my xml in a folder named "X" for example, and put this line in my build right ? <xslt style="./rules.xsl" basedir="X"  />

Comment: Yes you can play a little bit with folder and names if you want, Anyway I edit the answer to be more clear.

Comment: sorry .. i forgot to set the extension attributes ... i edit the answer again :)